# Snowflake exporting table with VARIANT column to parquet file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parquet, variant

I'm trying to export a Snowflake table to a parquet file. This table contains a VARIANT column with an array of JSON objects (array of struct to be more precise).

When exporting the table to parquet file, this VARIANT column gets exported as string. I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid this behavior and export the column as array of structs in parquet.

I think this could be possible because I run the following test:

1. Import a parquet file (containing a column with array of struct) to Snowflake
2. Check the type of this column in Snowflake => it's a VARIANT type
3. Export this exact table back to parquet => the column is now a string...

Edit: here is the SQL queries I used to export

```
COPY INTO @MY_STAGE/parquet_file_
FROM (SELECT variant_column FROM TABLE_A LIMIT 5)
file_format = (type = 'parquet')
header = true;
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Could you pleas add the SQL of the command you use to export?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, it cannot be done. See the note in the [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location): ```VARIANT columns are converted into simple JSON strings rather than LIST values, even if the column values are cast to arrays```

Comment: The documentation seems to be confusing as on the same page, under Usage Notes, it says "To unload the data as Parquet LIST values, explicitly cast the column values to arrays (using the TO_ARRAY function).". Probably worth try and seeing what happens

Comment: I gave a shot at the TO_ARRAY function but it didn't work unfortunately... 

It's a shame because I guess Snowflake has something internally to detect parquet schema (when loading the data from file to Snowflake table). So we it would have been nice to have this behavior when unloading data from Snowflake...